# Docker within Docker Container

Tags: docker

Im entering a docker container via:
`docker run -it ubuntu bash`

When im within the container, i am installing Docker:
`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Yet when I fire `dockerd` im getting:

```
INFO[2020-04-20T11:49:01.220025800Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: As I wrote in a comment on the linked question, starting the Docker daemon in a container is difficult and generally seen as unnecessary.  Use the host's Docker socket if you must directly run `docker` commands, but be aware that the ability to do this implies unrestricted root-level access over the host.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the docker container with CAP_NET_ADMIN capabilities so that the container has permission to perform various network-related operations.

So start the container via `docker run --cap-add CAP_NET_ADMIN -it ubuntu bash`.

See https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities